# RadioButton sets inversed value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following radio buttons in my view (XAML):

```
<RadioButton Content="Single bill" IsChecked="{Binding AccountingCreationData.IsSingleBill, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />

<RadioButton Content="Collective bill" IsChecked="{Binding AccountingCreationData.IsCollectiveBill, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="179"/>
```

The properties in my viewmodel are implemented like this (C#):

```
public bool IsSingleBill
{
    get { return _singleBill; }
    set
    {
        if (_singleBill != value)
        {
            _singleBill = value;
            IsCollectiveBill = !value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSingleBill");
        }
    }
}

public bool IsCollectiveBill
{
    get { return _collectiveBill; }
    set
    {
        if (_collectiveBill != value)
        {
            _collectiveBill = value;
            IsSingleBill = !value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsCollectiveBill");
        }
    }
}
```

However once I "check" the "Single bill" option, the value is `false` (but it should be `true`).

Once my view was loaded, there's no selected radio button (although I set `IsSingleBill = true` in my constructor).

Comment: I think you won't need `IsCollectiveBill = !value;` and `IsSingleBill = !value;` in your setters because the radiobuttons will handle that themselves.

Comment: How should the RadioButton know to set `IsCollectiveBill = true` when the RadioButton for `IsSingleBill` is set?

Comment: You should drop the `BoolToVis` converters - `RadioButton.IsChecked` property is of type `bool?` and can be bound directly to a property of type `bool`. The converter is producing a value of type `Visibility` which is invalid - you should be able to observe appropriate message in the output window.

Comment: @mosquito87 you will have to group them (taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx): 
"When a RadioButton is selected, it cannot be cleared by clicking it. When RadioButton elements are grouped, the buttons are mutually exclusive. A user can select only one item at a time within a RadioButton group. You can group RadioButton controls by placing them inside a parent or by setting the GroupName property on each RadioButton."

Comment: @Grx70 your approach seems to be working fine! Thanks.